# Error al reproducir sonido compartido con shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

con un intent selecciono un archivo mp3 y guardo con URI la localización en preferencias compartidas tal como encontré en Google; en otro activity se lanza un elemento media player que rescata el uri. Pero...

- le doy play a reproducirlo y funciona
- cierro y abro app
- doy en el botón play y truena la app
- vuelvo a seleccionar un audio y ya funciona

El problema parece estar al cerrar y abrir. ¿Por qué?

Éste es el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    Button mp3,play;
    int u;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs=getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mp3=findViewById(R.id.mp3);
        play=findViewById(R.id.play);
        mp3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                elijemp3(v);
            }
        });
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,musica.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    public void elijemp3(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File("audio");
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this,file.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,file.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/mp3");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Audio (mp3) file"), 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)){
               Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
                ***String s=getRealPathFromUri(this,audioFileUri);***
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                ***editor.putString("urime", s);***
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
    public String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}


ESTE EL ES OTRO activity

     public class musica extends AppCompatActivity {

    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    public Uri urim;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer,mp;
    public String urimp3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_musica);

        prefs=getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        urimp3 = prefs.getString("urime", null);
            urim=Uri.parse(urimp3);
        playOnOffSound();
            // urim=Uri.parse("sdcard/bep.mp3");
      /*      mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), urim);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

    }

    private void playOnOffSound(){

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, urim);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       /*if(mediaPlayer!=null){
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }*/ if(mp!=null){
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       /* if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }*/ if(mp!=null)
        {
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
       /* if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }*/ if(mp!=null)
        {
            mp.pause();
        }
       /// musica.pause();
    }
}
```

Nada del otro mundo pero, ¿por qué no funciona? Éste es el error que recibo:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ya [intenté esta otra forma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwEYbH7wBIw) y nada. Recibo un nuevo error:

[image: este es el nuevo error]

Éste es el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    Button stop,play,examinar;
    String FilePathAudio;
    TextView url;
    private final int PICKER=1;
    private int state=1;
    private final int PLAYING=1;
    private final int PAUSING=2;

    Uri FilePath;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

      //  mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mp3);
       // mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        stop=findViewById(R.id.stop);
        play=findViewById(R.id.play);
        examinar=findViewById(R.id.examinar);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case PLAYING:
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        state=PAUSING;
                        play.setText("Pause");
                        break;
                    case PAUSING:
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        state=PLAYING;
                        play.setText("Play");
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                play.setText("Play");
            }
        });

        examinar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickfile();
            }
        });
    }
    private void pickfile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "selecione un audio"), PICKER);

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICKER:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    FilePath = data.getData();
                    FilePathAudio=getRealPathFromUri(FilePath);
                }
                try{
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(FilePathAudio);
                    //mediaPlayer.prepare();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    public String getRealPathFromUri (Uri contentUri){
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto puede tener varias causas desde el codec del archivo hasta permisos, requeriste permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Comment: como que el codec ?lo intento con varios archivos y hace lo mismo, en mi otro proyecto si tiene los permiso y hae lo mismo ese de la imagen lo hice aparte para probar con detalle

Comment: Si usas android 6.0 o mayor los permisos deben requerirse manualmente.

Comment: porque permiso de write si solo estoy leyendo el archivo? pongo los dos permisos?

Comment: En realidad el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE implica el permiso READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, así que solo necesitas el de write, aunque no desees escribir.

Comment: ya se los puse y no.aun no funciona

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que el `MediaPlayer.create()` te esta devolviendo `null`. Esto se podria deber a varias razones, como permisos, archivo corrupto o inexistente, etc. Pero teniendo en cuenta que a vos te funciona cuando lo ejecutas por primera vez, ya podemos descartar la mayoría.

*Así guarda el string en shared:*

[image: asi guarda el string en shared]

El problema debe ser que no estas liberando adecuadamente el recurso y entonces al ejecutar la app nuevamente, no puede crear el `MediaPlayer`, el archivo al que intenta acceder ya esta tomado y devuelve `null`.

Si ponemos juntos el código del `onPause` y `onDestroy` de tu código lo verás mas claramente:

```
//onPause
musica.pause();
//onDestroy
if(musica.isPlaying()){ //Siempre es falso porque fue pausado antes.
   musica.stop();
   musica.release(); //No se ejecuta y el recurso no se libera.
}
```

Yo te recomendaría que liberes el recurso de esta forma, que pienso yo es la mas segura:

```
@Override
protected void onStop(){
   if(mediaPlayer != null){
      mediaPlayer.release();
      mediaPlayer = null;
   }
}
```

y borra el código del `onDestroy()` al agregar esto sino romperá al querer hacerle `release()` a `mediaPlayer` que ahora es `null`.

---

Ahora que agregaste el print del debug pude ver que ademas estas guardando la URI incorrectamente.

Estás guardando `content://media...` esa no es una URI real, por eso no logra abrir el archivo después de haber cerrado la app.

Lo que debes hacer es transformar la URI del `content` en un path absoluto antes de guardarlo.

El código para transformarlo seria algo así:

```
public String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tiene sentido lo que dices solo que no funciono :C

Comment: gracias, hice las modificaciones que mencionaste aunque sigue haciendo lo mismo,si es valido lo que hago de hacer getData() para ponerlo en URI con sharedprefrences y usar el mediaplayer con setDataSource? o de que otra manera puedo hacer lo mismo?

Comment: ahi edite la respuestas agregando lo que creo que te solucionará el problema esta vez.

Comment: agregue lo que me dijiste y ahora dice Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener)' on a null object reference
        desde la primera vez que ejecuto el mediaplayer